# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded in python script

Tags: python, json

```
import json    
import requests    
import pprint    
from datetime import datetime    
url = 'url'    
cursor = context.cursor()   
cursor.execute('SELECT * from table')    
for a in cursor.fetchall():     
  urlpost = url + '/'+'Id'+'/data'     
  data = { "Id": str(a[0]),     
      "Name": "null",     
      "Type": str(a[4])    
  }    
  data_json = json.dumps(data)     
  headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}     
  response = requests.post(urlpost, data=data_json, headers=headers)    
  pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

I trying to put data from table to API.But getting error "Value Error: No JSON object could be decoded".I don't know what is missing!

Comment: Put `print(response.content)` instead of `pprint.pprint(response.json())` and you will see why you are not getting a valid JSON.

Comment: Thank u its working fine